# Definition of Asymptotically Flat at Null, Spacelike, and Timelike Infinities

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, causality, research-level, asymptotics

Most books I've looked into discuss asymptotic flatness in general relativity for the null and spacelike case (e.g. Wald), or for the null and timelike case (e.g. arXiv: [1706.09666 [math-ph]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09666)), but I can't seem to find a definition of asymptotic flatness that covers all three infinities at once. This seems important to me because, at first glance, I don't see a solid mathematical reason for the null infinity to be equal in both separate definitions, and I suppose there should be a definition that solves this hole.

Is there a complete definition of asymptotic flatness along the null, timelike, and spatial infinities? If so, what is it? If not, what is the difficulty in obtaining it?

Comment: Have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.17124, the paper discusses matchings through all five asymptotic regions. Presumably, this represents current state of the art.